# Program doesn't work - NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

I am using eclipse to export my project as a runnable jar file, when I try to run it nothing happens, when I run it using cmd I get this error.

```
C:\Users\Enes\Desktop>cmd.exe
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Enes\Desktop>java -jar Game.Jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scrolls.Resources.createArray(Resources.java:111)
        at scrolls.Player.<init>(Player.java:31)
        at scrolls.Draw.<init>(Draw.java:27)
        at scrolls.Frame.main(Frame.java:18)
        ... 5 more

C:\Users\Enes\Desktop>
```

When I run it using eclipse it runs fine with no errors or warnings.

This is my Resource file which seems to be causing the problem at line 111

```
package scrolls;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

public class Resources
{
    Map map;
    static BufferedImage[] textures = new BufferedImage[8];
    static BufferedImage[] mapTextures = new BufferedImage[9];
    static BufferedImage texture;
    static BufferedImage[] waterAnimated = new BufferedImage[64];
    static BufferedImage water;
    static BufferedImage icon;
    public static Font f, fs;
    static int imageCounter = 0;

    public Resources()
    {
        map = new Map();
        textures();
        createArray(texture, textures, 32, 1, 8);
        createArray(water, waterAnimated, 32, 64, 1);
        getFont();
        buildMapTextures(textures, mapTextures);
    }

    public static void counter()
    {
        imageCounter++;
        if (imageCounter >= 500)
            imageCounter = 0;
        //System.out.println(imageCounter / 8);
    }

    private void buildMapTextures(BufferedImage[] textures, BufferedImage[] mapTextures)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            mapTextures[i] = resize(textures[i], 3, 3);
        }
        mapTextures[8] = resize(waterAnimated[2], 3, 3);
    }

    private BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage image, int newW, int newH)
    {
        BufferedImage thumbnail = Scalr.resize(image, Scalr.Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT, newW, newH, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public static BufferedImage waterAnimation()
    {
        return waterAnimated[imageCounter / 8];
    }

    private void textures()
    {
        try
        {
            texture = ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/textures.png"));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
        }

        try
        {
            water = ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/water.png"));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
        }

        try
        {
            icon = ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/icon.png"));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
        }

    }

    static BufferedImage player()
    {
        BufferedImage player = null;
        try
        {
            player = ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/player.png"));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
        return player;
    }

    static void createArray(BufferedImage image, BufferedImage[] images, int size, int rows, int cols)
    {
        BufferedImage temp = image;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                images[(i * cols) + j] = temp.getSubimage(j * size, i * size, size, size); // line 111
            }
        }
    }

    public static void readLevel(String filename, int[][] level, int part)
    {
        try
        {
            File f = new File("src/resources/levels/" + part + "/" + filename + ".txt");
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            byte b = 0;
            while ((b = (byte) in.read()) != -1)
            {
                sb.append("" + ((char) b));
            }
            String str = sb.toString();
            String[] lines = str.split("(\n|\r)+");
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < lines[i].length(); j++)
                {
                    level[i][j] = Integer.parseInt("" + lines[i].charAt(j));
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void getFont()
    {
        try
        {
            f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("src/resources/Jet Set.ttf"));
            fs = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream("src/resources/Jet Set.ttf"));
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        f = f.deriveFont(22f);
        fs = fs.deriveFont(13f);
    }

}
```

Player code

```
package scrolls;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Player
{
    static int x, y, dx, dy;
    BufferedImage[] sprites = new BufferedImage[8];
    int rotation = 0;
    int imageCounter = 0;
    public static boolean moving = false;
    static int playerEnergy = 150000;
    static int playerLvl = 1;
    static int playerExp = 3;
    static int expNeeded = (((playerLvl + 1) * playerLvl) * 2);
    static int playerHealth = 100;
    static int playerMana = 100;
    static int mapRow = 6;
    static int mapColumn = 8;
    static int playerRow, playerColumn;

    public Player()
    {
        y = 40;
        x = 700;
        Resources.createArray(Resources.player(), sprites, 66, 1, 8);
    }

    private void changeImage()
    {
        imageCounter++;
        if (imageCounter >= 80)
            imageCounter = 0;
    }

    public void move()
    {
        y = y + dy;
        x = x + dx;
        changeImage();
        playerPosition();
    }

    static void mapPosition()
    {
        if (y < 0)
            playerRow = 0;
        else
            playerRow = (y / 32) + 1;
        if (x < 0)
            playerColumn = 0;
        else
            playerColumn = (x / 32) + 1;
    }

    private void playerPosition()
    {
        if (x >= 817 - 59)
        {
            x = -24;
            mapColumn++;
        }

        if (x <= -25)
        {
            x = 817 - 59;
            mapColumn--;
        }

        if (y <= -25)
        {
            y = 599 - 152 - 41;
            mapRow--;
        }
        if (y >= 599 - 152 - 40)
        {
            y = -24;
            mapRow++;
        }
    }

    public static int playerExp()
    {

        return playerExp;
    }

    public static int getNextExp()
    {
        return expNeeded;
    }

    public static int playerLvl()
    {
        if (playerExp >= expNeeded)
        {
            playerLvl++;
        }
        return playerLvl;
    }

    public static int playerHealth()
    {
        return playerHealth;
    }

    public static int playerMana()
    {
        return playerMana;
    }

    public static int playerEnergy()
    {
        if ((dx != 0) || (dy != 0))
            playerEnergy--;
        if ((dx != 0) && (dy != 0))
            playerEnergy--;

        return playerEnergy;
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage image, double angle)
    {
        double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
        int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
        int neww = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin), newh = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);

        GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
        BufferedImage result = gc.createCompatibleImage(neww, newh, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();

        g.translate((neww - w) / 2, (newh - h) / 2);
        g.rotate(angle, w / 2, h / 2);
        g.drawRenderedImage(image, null);
        g.dispose();

        return result;
    }

    public BufferedImage getPlayerImage()
    {

        roatePlayer();
        int image = animatePlayer();

        double angle = Math.toRadians(rotation);

        if (dy != 0 || dx != 0)
        {
            return rotate(sprites[image], angle);
        }
        return rotate(sprites[0], angle);

    }

    private int animatePlayer()
    {
        return imageCounter / 10;
    }

    private void roatePlayer()
    {
        if (dy > 0)
            rotation = 0;
        if (dy < 0)
            rotation = 180;
        if (dx > 0)
            rotation = -90;
        if (dx < 0)
            rotation = 90;

        if (dy > 0 && dx > 0)
            rotation = -45;
        if (dy > 0 && dx < 0)
            rotation = 45;
        if (dy < 0 && dx < 0)
            rotation = 135;
        if (dy < 0 && dx > 0)
            rotation = -135;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
        {
            dx = -1;
            rotation = -90;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
        {
            dy = 1;
            rotation = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        {
            dx = 1;
            rotation = 90;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
        {
            dy = -1;
            rotation = 180;
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
            dx = 0;

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
            dy = 0;

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
            dx = 0;

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
            dy = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to show the code obviously.

Comment: There is an error with your code that you could spot by debugging it. And crystall balls have stopped working in this era, so if you don't show us your code we can't help you.

Comment: @Renan: I'd say that the crystal balls are somewhat hazy but haven't *entirely* stopped working. More information would certainly help though...

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) `(Player.java:31)`  ..but what is on line 31 of `Player.java`?

Comment: As an aside, you mentioned compilation in the title & tags.  It seems like you are surprised that code could compile OK, but not run OK (outside of Eclipse).  That is commonly due to simple errors in the code, or the way the code does things.

Comment: I posted my code from Resource.java line 111 is                 images[(i * cols) + j] = temp.getSubimage(j * size, i * size, size, size); // line 111

Comment: Okay, so all we've proved so far (and you could have diagnosed this for yourself) is that the one of the first two arguments to the `createArray` method is null. So now we need to see the `Player` code...

Answer (score 7):

I strongly suspect that you're loading some resources (sounds, images) either by assuming that they're present as *files*, or you're using appropriate `getResource` / `getResourceAsStream` calls, but your resources aren't present in the jar file. We can't really tell without seeing any of your code or what's in your jar file, but you should check where you're loading the resource, and why you expect the resource to be found.

Oh, and you may have a casing issue too - when it's loading resources from the Windows file system, asking for `FOO.PNG` will work even if the file is called `foo.png`; the same is *not* true when loading resources from a jar file.

Of course, you should look at `Resources.java` line 111 and `Player.java` line 31 to help pin down exactly what's going wrong (e.g. which resource is failing).

EDIT: Okay, now that we've got the code, it's *exactly* as I first suggested. This line of code in `Resource.player()`:

```
player = ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/player.png"));
```

... is loading `player.png` expecting it to be a *file* on the local file system. You want something like:

```
player = ImageIO.read(Resource.class.getResource("/src/resources/player.png"));
```

It's odd to have a `src` folder in your jar file, by the way. If you've *actually* just got the image in a `reources` directory, you'd want:

```
player = ImageIO.read(Resource.class.getResource("/resources/player.png"));
```

Comment: I checked the jar file with Winrar and all the files are there. This is the line the seems to be causing the problem, eclipse compiles fine and give no errors 

images[(i * cols) + j] = temp.getSubimage(j * size, i * size, size, size);

I posted the full code above

Comment: @user2457344: Well what is `temp`? How is it initialized? You've still given us *no code whatsoever*, nor any indication of what file you're loading. I strongly suspect it's one of the three problems I listed, but I can give you *no more help* without more information.

Comment: @user2457344: Well you've now posted `Resource.java`, but we need `Player.java` as well. Have you performed *any* diagnosis on this yourself first? Tried to work out what's null? Added any logging? I'm sorry, but we really shouldn't be having to drag information out of you like this. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @user2457344: Right, and after all that it was in the first point in my answer from the start. Please take a step back and work out a) what diagnosis you could have done before asking the question; b) how you could have posted a better question (with only *relevant* code); c) how you could have checked your code against the options in my answer to spot the problem based on my answer.

Comment: I think it might be this line 
  Resources.createArray(Resources.player(), sprites, 66, 1, 8);
In Player class, I am calling before sprites in initialized, Ill try to find a better place to call it and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: @user2457344: No, it's because of what `Resources.player()` does. I've edited my answer to point that out. It's not an initialization order problem - it's that you're trying to load the resource from a local file which doesn't exist.

Comment: I got solved, but it doesn't like the way I import my font, is something wrong with the way I do it?

Comment: @user2457344: Ask that in a separate question, with only the relevant bits of code, and a *lot* more specific detail than "it doesn't like the way I import my font". Read through both of the pages I linked to earlier, carefully, and bear them in mind when you next ask a question. Be aware that if you ask several bad questions, you will be banned from asking questions.